# Common python rpc and cli interface

Tags: python, command-line-interface, rpc, argparse

I have a cli app which uses argparse and would like to add an rpc interface with pyjsonrpc.

It seems I will have to duplicate a lot of code and maintain two interfaces which I would rather not do.

Is there a way generate one from the other or have an abstract interface that generates both?

Comment: There are some RPC libraries that generate an equivalent CLI interface, but it's definitely not a feature that all or even most of them have, and if you want to use a specific one, just look and see if it has that feature.

Comment: Could you sketch the sort of `argparse` and `rpc` interfaces that you have in mind?  Will the `rpc` interface handle JSON expressions, that translate into a Python dictionaries?  How would it compare to a dictionary produced by `vars(parser.parse_args())`?

Comment: Ipython generates its `argparse` argument from entries in its `config` files.  So the user can use the default configs, profile configs, and/or the command line to set a large number of parameters.  `test_argparse.py` also generates most test cases with a parameter shorthand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find an adequate solution so I decided to write a small lib that generates the cli and rpc interface from a basic definition class.

Once its refined I will add it to the pypi, currently its available at https://github.com/F483/apigen

Edit: pypi package 'apigen' is now available https://pypi.python.org/pypi/apigen

Comment: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/plac is an argparse generator that uses `inspect` to populate the parser based on function arguments.  It also enhances the subparser part.

Comment: But it doesn't help me with my jsonrpc interface and the hole point was to have a common api for both.